# Unix Shell Script to Connect to Sybase DB to retrieve table data

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I need a unix shell/perl script which connects to Sybase DB to retrieve first 3 columns data in a table

I tried below code:

```
#!/bin/ksh

results=`isql -U<username> -P<password> -S<server name> <<EOF
select name from sysobjects where type = "U"
go
EOF`
line_count=0
echo "${results}" | while read line; do
   echo "Line $((line_count = line_count + 1)) is ${line}"
done
```

But when I execute this code i am getting error as isql not found. So I suspect that I have to set some environment before running this script. I have jdk and jconn3 jar ready with me. So can u please help me knowing how to set the environment in my script ?

Comment: Have you tried anything or you are just trying to get a direct answer for this.

Comment: Hi. I tried using korn script. Now I have modified the question also. Can u pls check and help me?

Comment: Do you have `isql` installed? Can you run it from the command line yourself?